# Select <select> elements that have the multiple attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I don't know what these are called, the thing that the element is (not the class or id), for example:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleSelect2">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

[Source](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#form-controls)

In this case, I want to select `$('select multiple')`, so that it picks up any element with both the `select` and `multiple` names. What is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`multiple` is  boolean attribute and you can use attr selector like this `$('select[multiple]')`

```js
$('select[multiple]').css('background', 'blue');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleSelect2">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```